# Unreachable condition in while and if statement, one compile, the other one doesn't

Tags: java

```
while(false){
    x = 3;
}

if(false){
    x = 5;
```

The compiler will complain and not compile the `while` statement, unreachable code. But it still compile for the `if` statement to have unreachable code. Reason?

Comment: It's not fine for the `if`. You get a warning about *dead code*.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza true.but the code still compile. I wonder why it is designed  this way?